# Perl -pi -e cannot substitute lines with asterisk - maybe I'm not escaping properly

Tags: bash, perl, escaping

I've been using the perl pie mentioned in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131528/what-does-exactly-perl-pi-e-do) without success. What am I doing wrong:

```
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

I want the file to end up looking like this after doing perl pie

```
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require iziToast
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

I wasted one hour with silly attempts like this:

```
  828  perl -pi -e 's/  *= require_tree ./  *= Require_tree ./' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
  832  perl -pi -e 's/require_tree \./Require_tree \./' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
  837  perl -pi -e 's/  \*\= require_tree \./  \*\= Require_tree \./' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
  839  perl -pi -e 's/= require_tree \./= Require_tree \./'       864  perl -pi -e 's/\*/\Q*/' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
  868  perl -pi -e 's/\*/\Q*/' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
  874  perl -pi -e 's/\*/*/' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
  876  perl -pi -e 's/\*/\*/' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
  878  perl -pi -e 's/\*/s/' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
  898  git checkout app/; perl -pi -e 's/\(\*\)/$1/' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss; git diff
  900  git checkout app/; perl -pi -e 's/(*)/$1/' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss; git diff
  901  git checkout app/; perl -pi -e 's/(\*)/$1/' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss; git diff
  903  git checkout app/; perl -pi -e 's/(\\*)/$1/' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss; git diff
  905  git checkout app/; perl -pi -e 's/\(\*\)/$1/' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss; git diff
  907  git checkout app/; perl -pi -e 's/^(.*)/foo/' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss; git diff
  908  git checkout app/; perl -pi -e 's/^  (.*)/foo/' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss; git diff
  924  git checkout app/; perl -pi -e 's/^(.*)/\1/' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss; git diff
  925  git checkout app/; perl -pi -e 's/^(.*)/\\1/' app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss; git diff
```

System: Mac 10.13.5, bash 3.2, perl 5.18

Notes: A line number based approach is not ideal for me because line numbers are not very future-proof
Since question title mentions perl, looking for a perl answer.

Comment: Do you want to add before the line with `require_tree`, or do you want to change the line with `require_tree`?

Comment: as long as we end up with the output looking exactly as mentioned in the question, i don't care

Comment: Then you could simply do: `perl -piE '/\*= require_tree/ and say " *= require iziToast"' test.css` to add the line `" *= require iziToast"` before the line with `require_tree`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` and `.` are special in regex patterns. You must use `\*` and `\.` to match `*` and `.`.

```
perl -i -pe'print " *= require iziToast\n" if /^ \*= require_tree \.$/' file
```

or

```
perl -i -pe's/^(?= \*= require_tree \.$)/ *= require iziToast\n/' file
```

Comment: why did you resort to using an if conditional. why can't s/// do it

Comment: by the way the capitalization changes were just trash/experiments. The real task is adding "*= require iziToast" just before the "*= require_tree ."

Comment: I "resorted" to using `print` because I wanted to print something, not replace something :) But yeah, you could use s///. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even use Perl for this; you can simply use `sed`.

```
$ sed '3i\
> \ *= require iziToast
> ' tmp.txt
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require iziToast
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

Comment: OP said that a solution based on line numbers won't work. Picture the line he wants to insert before being the 200th line, not the 3rd